# Is there any way to speed up this MSSQL 2012 View?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view, sql-server-2012, query-optimization

Here's the declaration for the View:

```
USE [calendar2014]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE view [dbo].[AdminRegisteredCards] WITH SCHEMABINDING as 
    SELECT ISNULL(ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER (ORDER BY ta.CreatedOn, ta.ItemId), -1000) AS AdminRegisteredCardsId,
    ta.ItemId,
    ta.CardNumber, 
    ta.FirstName, 
    ta.LastName, 
    ta.Birthday, 
    ta.PostalCode, 
    ta.[Description], 
    ta.CardActivated, 
    ta.ContactInfo, 
    ta.PhoneNumber,
    ta.ReceiveCalendarReminders, 
    ta.ReceiveGeneralMails, 
    ta.ReceivePrefStoreMails, 
    ta.CardStatus, 
    ta.SamoaCardId, 
    ta.CalendarUserId, 
    ta.LiveOpsRegistrantId,
    ta.UseType,
    ta.CreatedOn,
    ta.ModifiedBy, 
    ta.ModifiedOn 
    from (
        SELECT CalendarUser.CalendarUserId as ItemId,
        SamoaCard.CardNumber,
        SamoaCard.FirstName,
        SamoaCard.LastName,
        CalendarUser.Birthday,
        CalendarUser.PostalCode,
        RegisterSourceType.[Description],
        CalendarUserCard.CardActivated,
        CalendarUser.EmailAddress as ContactInfo,
        CalendarUser.PhoneNumber,
        CalendarUser.ReceiveCalendarReminders,
        CalendarUser.ReceiveGeneralMails,
        CalendarUser.ReceivePrefStoreMails,
        CASE WHEN CalendarUserCard.CardDeactivated IS NOT NULL THEN 'Deactivated' ELSE 'Activated' END AS CardStatus,
        SamoaCard.SamoaCardId,
        CalendarUser.CalendarUserId,
        null as LiveOpsRegistrantId,
        SamoaCard.CreatedOn,
        'C' as UseType,
        CalendarUser.ModifiedBy,
        CalendarUser.ModifiedOn 
        FROM dbo.CalendarUser CalendarUser
         INNER JOIN dbo.RegisterSourceType RegisterSourceType
          ON CalendarUser.RegisterType = RegisterSourceType.RegisterType
         INNER JOIN dbo.CalendarUserCard CalendarUserCard
          ON CalendarUserCard.CalendarUserId = CalendarUser.CalendarUserId
         INNER JOIN dbo.SamoaCard SamoaCard
          ON CalendarUserCard.SamoaCardId = SamoaCard.SamoaCardId

        UNION ALL

        SELECT LiveOpsRegistrant.LiveOpsRegistrantId as ItemId, 
            LiveOpsRegistrant.CardNumber,
            'Registered' as FirstName,
            'Card' as LastName,
            LiveOpsRegistrant.Birthday,
            null as PostalCode,
            'LiveOps' as Description,
            LiveOpsRegistrant.CreatedOn as CardActivated,
            LiveOpsRegistrant.PhoneNumber as ContactInfo,
            LiveOpsRegistrant.PhoneNumber,
            CONVERT(bit,0) as ReceiveCalendarReminders,
            CONVERT(bit,0) as ReceiveGeneralMails,
            CONVERT(bit,0) as ReceivePrefStoreMails,
            'Activated' AS CardStatus,
            SamoaCard.SamoaCardId,
            null as CalendarUserId,
            LiveOpsRegistrant.LiveOpsRegistrantId,
            SamoaCard.CreatedOn,
            'L' as UseType,
            SamoaCard.ModifiedBy,
            SamoaCard.ModifiedOn
        FROM dbo.LiveOpsRegistrant LiveOpsRegistrant
         INNER JOIN dbo.SamoaCard SamoaCard
          ON LiveOpsRegistrant.CardNumber = SamoaCard.CardNumber
    ) ta;
```

Currently this view is taking a *very* long time to access - we have about 1.4 million records.

Is there some way to optimize this View?

Comment: @SaUce - That's not quite accurate. The nested sub-query has the potential to be an issue. If the OP is using a new-ish version of SQL Server, common table expressions might be able to help.

Comment: @JustinNiessner: Yes, I'm using MSSQL 2012.

Comment: The extra parentheses on `JOIN ON` clauses are not necessary and can be a bit confusing. Why would you use `ISNULL` with `ROW_NUMBER()`?

Comment: not that I formatted your code it is easier to see sub selects and  extra parentheses

Comment: @Serg Could you post some DDL and possible indexes here?

Comment: @NickyvV: We don't have any indexes on this view since we can't add them. MSSQL complains that the view is a composite table.

Comment: since you are using `SCHEMABINDING` option anyway why not consider making it indexed views and see hows the performance then [Read here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx) for more information about indexed views

Comment: First check out the query plan of the two source queries and optimize them.  If you have indexes on join conditions then there is not much more you can do.  That sort on the union is what I suspect is the big hit.

Comment: @Serg NickyvV is talking about the underlying tables. Surely they have schema and indexes...

Comment: Do you have an option of doing it in a query as then you you could use #temp?

Comment: @Blam : Views don't have Temp table...

Comment: @Serg:  Yes, there is a way to boost your view. 1) The subquery is causing the issue here. Instead of subquery Use CTE at top and link multiple cte. 2) Write a Select Statement based on the cte by joining CTE.

Comment: @Maverick That is why I said "option of doing it in a query as then"

Comment: @Maverick: Can you write what that would look like as an answer? I have no idea what CTE is and Google is failing me.

Comment: @Serg: you mentioned there are 1.4M rows. is it in the final result or total sum of records in all the tables used? what is the number of rows in each table and is the growth of data in all table almost equal? for example I guess table CalendarUser is receives new data once in a while but lets say Table "LiveOpsRegistrant" gets new data every day. these numbers are to just see what table affects the most this select performance. Also how slow the current query is? is it never ending, 10 min, 2 min? and what is the acceptable execution time?

Comment: after seeing the attempt by Maverick, i am trying to replace UNION ALL with something else. but for that I need table definitions. Cane you post table+sample data on SQL fiddle or here. what i am interested in is if we can include the LiveOpsRegistrant in the same first select stmt then we definitely get some boost because UNION ALL is twice the table/index scan in your current query. Also trying to remove the Constants in inner select queries. imagine your sub query has 500k rows and 3%0 of columns are constant value. we do not need to handle that temp data. we can do it on Outermost query.

Comment: continuing my above questions. table SamoaCard is join with Table CalendarUserCard on SamoaCardId column and JOIN with table LiveOpsRegistrant  on CardNumber  column. that means table SamoaCard has both "CardNumber" and "SamoaCardId" columns. so what is the relation between them. for a given singe row, can those both column has value or only one column out of that two can have value in that table?

Answer (score 0):

```
USE [calendar2014]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE view [dbo].[AdminRegisteredCards]


    WITH inCalender AS(
        SELECT CalendarUser.CalendarUserId as ItemId,
        SamoaCard.CardNumber,
        SamoaCard.FirstName,
        SamoaCard.LastName,
        CalendarUser.Birthday,
        CalendarUser.PostalCode,
        RegisterSourceType.[Description],
        CalendarUserCard.CardActivated,
        CalendarUser.EmailAddress as ContactInfo,
        CalendarUser.PhoneNumber,
        CalendarUser.ReceiveCalendarReminders,
        CalendarUser.ReceiveGeneralMails,
        CalendarUser.ReceivePrefStoreMails,
        CASE WHEN CalendarUserCard.CardDeactivated IS NOT NULL THEN 'Deactivated' ELSE 'Activated' END AS CardStatus,
        SamoaCard.SamoaCardId,
        CalendarUser.CalendarUserId,
        null as LiveOpsRegistrantId,
        SamoaCard.CreatedOn,
        'C' as UseType,
        CalendarUser.ModifiedBy,
        CalendarUser.ModifiedOn 
        FROM dbo.CalendarUser CalendarUser
         INNER JOIN dbo.RegisterSourceType RegisterSourceType
          ON CalendarUser.RegisterType = RegisterSourceType.RegisterType
         INNER JOIN dbo.CalendarUserCard CalendarUserCard
          ON CalendarUserCard.CalendarUserId = CalendarUser.CalendarUserId
         INNER JOIN dbo.SamoaCard SamoaCard
          ON CalendarUserCard.SamoaCardId = SamoaCard.SamoaCardId
),inLive AS(

        SELECT LiveOpsRegistrant.LiveOpsRegistrantId as ItemId, 
            LiveOpsRegistrant.CardNumber,
            'Registered' as FirstName,
            'Card' as LastName,
            LiveOpsRegistrant.Birthday,
            null as PostalCode,
            'LiveOps' as Description,
            LiveOpsRegistrant.CreatedOn as CardActivated,
            LiveOpsRegistrant.PhoneNumber as ContactInfo,
            LiveOpsRegistrant.PhoneNumber,
            CONVERT(bit,0) as ReceiveCalendarReminders,
            CONVERT(bit,0) as ReceiveGeneralMails,
            CONVERT(bit,0) as ReceivePrefStoreMails,
            'Activated' AS CardStatus,
            SamoaCard.SamoaCardId,
            null as CalendarUserId,
            LiveOpsRegistrant.LiveOpsRegistrantId,
            SamoaCard.CreatedOn,
            'L' as UseType,
            SamoaCard.ModifiedBy,
            SamoaCard.ModifiedOn
        FROM dbo.LiveOpsRegistrant LiveOpsRegistrant
         INNER JOIN dbo.SamoaCard SamoaCard
          ON LiveOpsRegistrant.CardNumber = SamoaCard.CardNumber
    ) 

    Select 
 ISNULL(ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER (ORDER BY I.CreatedOn, I.ItemId), -1000) AS AdminRegisteredCardsId,
    I.ItemId,
    I.CardNumber, 
    I.FirstName, 
    I.LastName, 
    I.Birthday, 
    I.PostalCode, 
    I.[Description], 
    I.CardActivated, 
    I.ContactInfo, 
    I.PhoneNumber,
    I.ReceiveCalendarReminders, 
    I.ReceiveGeneralMails, 
    I.ReceivePrefStoreMails, 
    I.CardStatus, 
    I.SamoaCardId, 
    I.CalendarUserId, 
    I.LiveOpsRegistrantId,
    I.UseType,
    I.CreatedOn,
    I.ModifiedBy, 
    I.ModifiedOn 
    from inCalender I Left outer join
    inLive L on I.ItemId = L.CardNumber
```

Note:
  Based on what I assumed I wrote it. I don't know what are the keys that should be used as a part of join. It can be done accordingly.
Don't be surprise if you get any duplicate records so you can put a distinct in the select statement or join with appropriate join that problem will be taken care of.

Comment: you suggesting the "Left Outer Join" where original query has "Union ALL" ?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments if you can get me these details will be happy to look over it and see if we can further optimize it. mean while here the smaller scale example to illustrate how i was planning to replace "UNION ALL" with "FULL OUTER JOIN"

the reason for going to this approach is this is only one time select and you will not have any sub query. so no overhead of holding data retrieved by inner query and pass it to out query.

you can see that I have assume one one of my comment is true in this below example that "in the Table SamoaCard there no single row will have value in both columns SamoaCardId and CardNumber at the same time"

```
    DECLARE @CalendarUserCard TABLE
    (
        SamoaCardId INT NOT NULL
        ,name       sysname NOT NULL
    )

    DECLARE @LiveOpsRegistrant TABLE
    (
         CardNumber             INT NOT NULL
        ,LiveOpsRegistrantId    sysname NOT NULL
    )

    DECLARE @SamoaCard  TABLE
    (
        SamoaCardId     INT NULL
        ,CardNumber         INT NULL

    )

    INSERT INTO @CalendarUserCard ( SamoaCardId, name ) SELECT 1,'CalendarUserCard 1'   UNION ALL SELECT 2,'CalendarUserCard 2'
    INSERT INTO @LiveOpsRegistrant ( CardNumber, LiveOpsRegistrantId ) SELECT 3,'LiveOpsRegistrantId 3' UNION ALL SELECT 4,'LiveOpsRegistrantId 4'
    INSERT INTO @SamoaCard ( SamoaCardId,CardNumber  ) SELECT 1,NULL UNION ALL SELECT 2,NULL UNION ALL SELECT NULL,3 UNION ALL SELECT NULL,4

    SELECT * FROM @CalendarUserCard
    SELECT * FROM @LiveOpsRegistrant
    SELECT * FROM @SamoaCard

    SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN SamoaCard.SamoaCardId IS NULL THEN 'Value From LiveOpsRegistrant'
            WHEN SamoaCard.CardNumber IS NULL THEN 'Value From CalendarUserCard'
        END TestAttributeColumn
        ,CASE 
            WHEN SamoaCard.SamoaCardId IS NULL THEN 'Registered'
            WHEN SamoaCard.CardNumber IS NULL THEN CalendarUserCard.name
        END FirstName
        ,CASE 
            WHEN SamoaCard.SamoaCardId IS NULL THEN 'L'
            WHEN SamoaCard.CardNumber IS NULL THEN 'C'
        END UseType
        ,CASE 
            WHEN SamoaCard.SamoaCardId IS NULL THEN LiveOpsRegistrant.LiveOpsRegistrantId
            WHEN SamoaCard.CardNumber IS NULL THEN NULL
        END AS LiveOpsRegistrantId
    FROM @CalendarUserCard CalendarUserCard
    INNER JOIN @SamoaCard SamoaCard
        ON CalendarUserCard.SamoaCardId = SamoaCard.SamoaCardId
    FULL OUTER JOIN @LiveOpsRegistrant LiveOpsRegistrant
        ON SamoaCard.CardNumber = LiveOpsRegistrant.CardNumber
```

[image]